# Wait Until Data is Fetched from MongoDB React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a Quiz App. This is the Quiz Page Code. Quiz DB Document contains a `QuizQuestions` Array which has question ids. Then I fetch specific question from MCQ/Question DB. Fetching MCQ takes time and when I `console.log` fetched data. First and second time data in undefined then its viewable. Due to this I'm unable to display it as it cause `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined mcqOptions` How can I fix this?[image]
`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import shuffleMcq from "../components/shuffleMcq";

const QuizTakePage = ({ match }) => {
  const reqUrl = match.params.path; //Getting Quiz ID From URL
  const [quizInfo, setQuizInfo] = useState({
    "q_title":"",
    "q_seo_description":"",
    "q_questions":[],
    "q_tags":[],
    "m_subject":"", })
  //const fetchQuizData = fetch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuizData = async () => {
        const reqApiUrl = '/quiz/api/qid/'+reqUrl;
        const fetchedApiResult = await fetch(reqApiUrl);
        const resultJson = await fetchedApiResult.json();
        setQuizInfo(resultJson);
    }
    fetchQuizData();  }, []);
// Quiz Data START
const quizTitle = quizInfo.q_title;
const quizDesc = quizInfo.q_seo_description;
const quizQuestions = quizInfo.q_questions;
// Quiz Data END
// MCQ Data START
const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
const requestedQuestion = quizQuestions[currentQuestion];
const [mcqInfo, setMcqInfo] = useState({
  "m_title":"",
  "m_question":"",
  "m_alternatives":[],
  "m_language":"",  })
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchApiResponse = async () => {
  const reqApiUrl = '/mcq/api/mid/'+requestedQuestion;
  const fetchedApiResult = await fetch(reqApiUrl);
  const resultJson = await fetchedApiResult.json();
  setMcqInfo(resultJson);
  }
  fetchApiResponse(); }, [requestedQuestion]);
  //const mcqLanguage = mcqInfo.m_language;
  const mcqQuestion = mcqInfo.m_question;
  const mcqOptions = mcqInfo.m_alternatives;
  console.log(mcqOptions);
  return (
    <>
    <h1>{quizTitle}</h1>
    <p>{quizDesc}</p> 
    </>
  );
   
};
export default QuizTakePage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `undefined` for the first and second time is due to the fact that `useEffect` would've not been executed by then. `useEffect` runs when the component is rendered and mounted for the first time, and then subsequent executions are made when there is a change in dependency array (If there are any dependencies).
You could get rid of the error by rendering the dynamic content conditionally, i.e, displaying it when the data has been fetched.

```
return (
    <>
    <h1>{quizTitle.length>0 ? quizTitle : "Loading Question"}</h1>
    <p>{quizDesc.length>0 ? quizDesc: "Loading Description"}</p>
    <ul>
      {mcqOptions && mcqOptions.length>0 && mcqOptions.map(option=>{
        return(<li key={Math.random()}>{option}</li>) //Using Math.random() for key to ensure all the mapped items have an unique key
      }
      }
    </ul>
    </>
  );
```

Alternatively, if your `mcqOptions` is an array of `objects` you can `map` it accordingly, for instance, something like this,

```
<ul>
      {mcqOptions && mcqOptions.length>0 && mcqOptions.map(mcqOption=>{
        return(<li key={mcqOption.id}>{mcqOption.text}</li>) //Use the properties accordingly, this is an example only.
      }
      }
</ul>
```

Comment: `mcqOptions` which is an array is the one that causing problem. How can I render array conditionally?

Comment: Is it an array of strings or objects?

Comment: Strings but I can turn them in objects if it solves the problem

Comment: I've updated the answer, kindly check.

Comment: Your answer is correct at all, but in this case, a simple mistake causes the `undefiend` error on getting variables.